# Error 1267 en MARIADB: Ilegal mix of collations

Tags: mariadb

Estoy asignando en MariaDB un valor varchar a una variable de consola para poder filtrar una tabla, pero me sale error 1267.

```
SET @filtro_etario = '1_Hasta 30 años';

SELECT * FROM dim_cliente 
WHERE Rango_Etario = @filtro_etario;
```

Comment: La collation es la página de códigos de los caracteres contenidos en un campo de una tabla, que puede ser individual o bien compartido en toda la tabla o bien de toda la base de datos.  El texto descriptivo de ese error dice "Illegal mix of collations", lo que me hace suponer que mariadb/mysql se da cuenta que los caracteres que intentas usar en tu consulta no comparten la misma página de códigos. Revisa las páginas de codigos tanto del campo dim_cliente en la estructura de la base de datos, como del archivo que contiene ese filtro_etario con la "ñ", y seguramente son distintos y de ahí el mix

Comment: bueno ya verifique q todas mis tablas esten con collation utf8mb4_spanish_ci, e incluso ya estableci a mi base de datos con ese collation

Comment: ¿Eso quiere decir que lo has solucionado o sigues con el problema?  Y ojo con ese cambio pues si tenias datos es probable que algunos se hayan corrompido... si cambias collations sin controlar eso puedes tener problemas. Lo mejor era exportar la base de datos primero (copia de seguridad) y luego hacerlo comprobando que no hubiera corrupcion de datos.

Comment: aun no me soluciona... bueno mi bade de datos estaba en utf8mb3_general_ci y lo cambie a utf8mb4_spanish_ci... lo de mis tablas si la mayoria o almenos la q estoy usando en esta consulta si estaba en utf8mb4_spanish_ci... pero aun asi me da error con esta especificacion: Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_spanish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='... entonces que codificacion estaria mal ? de la variable o la tabla dim_cliente?

Comment: ¿La consulta como la estas haciendo?  ¿Desde un archivo? ¿o un gestor web tipo phpmyadmin?  ¿o lo haces desde un terminal? Debes revisar la codificación del archivo o de la web desde la que lo estes haciendo... ¿estas en windows o linux u otra cosa?

Comment: Revisa [esta página](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/setting-character-sets-and-collations/) a ver si puedes dar con el fallo... creo que lo estas haciendo desde consola (terminal) y alli hablan bastante de eso

Answer (score 1):

Bueno la solucion podría describirla de esta manera, dado que los valores de la tabla que estoy evaluando tienen caracteres latinos, le tengo que especificar el collate que usa esta tabla para definir la columna en consulta, antes de poder igualarlo con la variable creada y de esta manera evitarnos incompatibilidades.

```
set @rango_etario = '1_Hasta 30 años';

select * from dim_cliente 
where Rango_Etario collate UTF8MB4_SPANISH_CI = @rango_etario;
```

Comment: Bien, me alegro que ya lo hayas solucionado :-)

Comment: gracias   – 
masterguru